# Reactor Sink that emits only 1 event at a time?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I am playing with Replaying Reactor Sinks, I am trying to achieve a mix of a unicast and a replay processor. I would like it to emit to only one subscriber at the same (UnicastProcessor), but that it can also emit a default value on subscribe (ReplayProcessor). Here is something similar to the real case:

```
Flux<Boolean> monoC = Sinks.many().replay().latestOrDefault(true).asFlux().doOnNext(integer -> System.out.println(new Date() + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "    emiting next"));
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        monoC.flatMap(unused ->
                webClientBuilder.build()
                        .get()
                        .uri("https://www.google.com")
                        .retrieve()
                        .toEntityFlux(String.class)
                        .doOnSuccess(stringResponseEntity -> {
                            System.out.println(new Date() + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "    finished processing");
                        })
        ).subscribe();
    }).start();
}
```

That is printing:

```
emiting next
...
emiting next
finished processing
...
finished processing
```

Instead, I would like it to print:

```
emiting next
finished processing
...
emiting next
finished processing
```

**Update**, some more clarifications on the real case scenario:

The real case scenario is: I have a Spring WebFlux application that acts like a relay, it receives a request on a specific endpoint A, and it relays it to another microservice B. This microservice can then reply with a 429 if I go too fast, and in a header with how long I have to wait before retrying again. The retrying thing I have already achieved it with a .retry operator and a Mono.delay, but in the meantime, I can receive another request on my first endpoint A which will have to be blocked until the Mono.delay finishes.

I am trying to achieve this with a Replay Sink, so that after receiving a 429, I emit a "false" to the sink and after Mono.delay is over, it emits a true to the sink, so if in the mean time I receive any further request on A it can filter out all the falses and wait for a true to be emitted.

The problem i have on top of that is that, when I receive too many request to relay on A, microservice B starts responding slow, and getting overloaded. Therefore, i would like to limit the rate that the Sink is emitting. To be precise, i would like the publisher to emit a value, but don't emit any more until the subscriber hits onCompleted.

Comment: i dont really understand your user case. What do you mean by `I would like it to accept only one subscriber, so following subscribers are hold until first completes.` please describe your actual user case.

Comment: So, if you see the example that i provide, i would like to serialize (sequentially with concurrency 1) all the GET request that are done from different places in my application.

Comment: i can read your code, but i dont care about your code, i want to know the user case. What is your intention, what are you building, what are you trying to do. Because in reactive we usually dont use `Thread` and the code is messy, so i dont understand what it is you are trying to do. If i unerstand what it is you want to do, maybe we can help you build it in a more correct reactive way.

Comment: there are several very strange things with your code, why the `latestOrDefault` of a boolean? why are you `flatMap`ing over `monoC` and not using the boolean? you code is way off, in how to use sinks

Comment: i suggest you read the sink part in reactor documentation, which describes how to use a sink. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors

Comment: I have updated the question, with a more detailed explanation on the real case. Hope it can be understood, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: what you want is a queue, most likely not a sink.

Comment: You mean a workqueueprocessor? Are they not getting deprecated in favor of Sinks? Can you please give me more hints on how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: No just a plain old queue. You place things in a queue, and the server takes from the queue in its own pace. There are 1000s of different queues out there.

Comment: Ah, alright, i was trying to do this 100% reactive, but I am starting to give up yeah. Problem i think is that the publisher is not aware of the onComplete of the subscribers right? Perhaps with the delaySubscription(publisher) i can try something....

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with `Problem i think is that the publisher is not aware of the onComplete of the subscribers right?` that statement.

Comment: I meant, that there is no way for a publisher to know when the subscriber is disposed right?

Comment: Still dont understand what you are asking for. Your problem seems convoluted and unecassary complicated. If you have a service that has bad performance. You set up a queue so that service A places something in the queue. Service B reads off the queue in the pace it can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I understood your issue correctly, you want the requests to B being  processed sequentially. In that case you should have a look at https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-

```
public final <V> Flux<V> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Publisher<? extends V>> mapper, int concurrency)
```

I think your case should look like

```
//sinks should be global variable for your controller, initialized in @PostConstruct
        var sinks = Sinks
                //unsafe is required for multithreading
                .unsafe()
                .many()
                .replay()
                .latest();
        sinks.asFlux()
                .doOnNext(it -> System.out.printf("%s is emitting %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), it))
                .flatMap(counter -> {
                    return webClientBuilder.build()
                            .get()
                            .uri("https://www.google.com")
                            .retrieve()
                            .toEntityFlux(String.class)
                            .doOnSuccess(stringResponseEntity -> {
                                System.out.println(counter + " " + new Date() + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "    finished processing with " + stringResponseEntity.getStatusCode());
                            })
                            .then(Mono.just(counter));
                    //concurrency = 1 causes the flatMap being handled only once in parallel
                }, 1)
                .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                //this subscription also must be done in @PostConstruct
                .subscribe(counter -> System.out.printf("%s completed in %s\n", counter, Thread.currentThread().getName()));

        //and this is your endpoint method
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int counter = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                var result = sinks.tryEmitNext(counter);
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    //mb in that case you should retry
                    System.out.printf("%s emitted %s. with fail: %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), counter, result);
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("%s successfully emitted %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), counter);
                }
            }).start();
        }
```